# Javascript code example copied into a pre-tag gets executed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add a piece of javascript code to a certain `<div>`.
I enclosed the code in pre and code tags, but when I actually run this the code gets *executed*. Obviously, that's not what I want at all.

```
    var code = '<pre><code><script type="text/javascript" src="http://source.com/test.js"><\/script>\n';
    code = code + '<script type="text/javascript">\n';
    code = code + '\tadimp.id = ' + 1 + ';\n';
    code = code + '\tadimp.type = ' + 1 + ';\n';
    code = code + '\tadimp.generate();\n';
    code = code + '<\/script></code></pre>';

    $("#code").html(code);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `&lt;` and `&gt;` for  < and > in this case. Try this

```
var code = '<pre><code>&lt;script type="text/javascript" src="http://source.com/test.js"&gt;&lt;\/script&gt;\n';
    code = code + '&lt;script type="text/javascript"&gt;\n';
    code = code + '\tadimp.id = ' + 1 + ';\n';
    code = code + '\tadimp.type = ' + 1 + ';\n';
    code = code + '\tadimp.generate();\n';
    code = code + '&lt;\/script&gt;</code></pre>';

 $("#code").html(code);
```

Comment: You'll need to convert the opening `<script>` tag also, so it doesn't assume the rest is part of the a script.

Comment: Your fingers were faster than mine. :)

Comment: @skerit - Hope it helped you.

Comment: I somehow thought anything in a <pre> tag was regarded as text... This helped a lot! :)

Answer (score 3):

Surprise! You just manufactured your own XSS vulnerability. *Always HTML-encode any data you put into HTML.* ("data" is anything you want to appear on screen.)

In the HTML DOM this is thankfully completely automatic. Just use the text property, not the HTML property.

```
var code = [
        '<script type="text/javascript" src="http://source.com/test.js"><\/script>',
        '<script type="text/javascript">',
        '\tadimp.id = ' + 1 + ';',
        '\tadimp.type = ' + 1 + ';',
        '\tadimp.generate();',
        '<\/script>'
    ].join('\n');

$('#code').text(code);
// --------^^^^
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/6qdBD/3/

Answer (score 1):

Pre tags format the text not necessarily keep what the text within them from being executed as html. Or in this case JavaScript. A better method would be to replace < and > with the html entities `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the < and > symbols use &lt and &gt

var code = '&ltscript type="text/javascript" src="http://source.com/test.js"&gt&lt/script&gt\n'

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to just simply replace the `< in <script tag to '&lt and at the end to '&gt.`

Answer (score 0):

> Since HTML tags are permitted inside PRE, you cannot just "insert" a text file into an HTML document by slapping `<PRE>` and `</PRE>` around them. You have to convert the &, < and > characters into entities first.

From http://htmlhelp.com/reference/wilbur/block/pre.html